# Discrepancy between AWS Glue and its Dev Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

My understanding is Dev Endpoints in AWS Glue can be used to develop code iteratively and then deploy it to a Glue job. I find this specially useful when developing Spark jobs because every time you run a job, it takes several minutes to launch a Hadoop cluster in the background. However, I am seeing a discrepancy when using Python shell in Glue instead of Spark. `Import pg` doesn't work in a Dev Endpoint I created using Sagemaker JupyterLab Python notebook, but works in AWS Glue when I create a job using Python shell. Shouldn't the same libraries exist in the dev endpoint that exist in Glue? What is the point of having a dev endpoint if you cannot reproduce the same code in both places (dev endpoint and the Glue job)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Python shell jobs would not launch a Hadooo Cluster in the backend as it does not give you a Spark environment for your jobs.
Secondly, since PyGreSQL is not written in Pure Python, it will not work with Glue's native environment (Glue Spark Job, Dev endpoint etc)
Thirdly, Python Shell has additional support for certain package built-in.

Thus, I don't see a point of using DevEndpoint for Python Shell jobs.